# How can I count to get by quarter in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

this is my code below. I am populating country to ship out their items. The shipping month is always showing 12 months in a year (Jan-Dec). I'm using dynamic pivot to make the shipping month on columns. I manage to populate as below. How can I add in to count by Quarter? Expected result as below.

```
create table #temp
(
    country varchar(20),
    ship varchar(3),
    amount money
)

insert into #temp values ('German', 'Jan', 1000.00)
insert into #temp values ('USA', 'Feb', 500.00)
insert into #temp values ('AUS', 'Feb', 800.00)
insert into #temp values ('AUS', 'Mar', 700.00)
insert into #temp values ('German', 'Apr', 1100.00)
insert into #temp values ('UK', 'May', 1100.00)
insert into #temp values ('Africa', 'Jun', 1100.00)

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ship) 
            FROM #temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @cols2 =STUFF(( select distinct ',IsNull(['+ship+'],0) as ['+ship+']' from #temp 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

--select @cols,@cols2

set @query = 'SELECT country, ' + @cols2 + '  from 
            (
                select country
                    , amount
                    , ship
                from #temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for ship in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

[image]

Comment: Considering that the months are the year are known, why use a dynamic Pivot? I don't have any expectations that the months of the year are going to change any time soon.

Comment: This looks like the pivot is straightforward (no need for dynamic as others have said) and the quarter subtotals are a presentation issue that you probably shouldnt be doing at the DB level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a dynamic pivot here, the months of the year are fixed and aren't subject to change. Code your pivot literally and adding quarters into it is trivial.

```sql
SELECT Country,
       SUM(CASE ship WHEN 'Jan' THEN amount END) AS Jan,
       SUM(CASE ship WHEN 'Feb' THEN amount END) AS Feb,
       SUM(CASE ship WHEN 'Mar' THEN amount END) AS Mar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ship IN ('Jan','Feb','Mar') THEN amount END) AS Q1,
       ...
       SUM(CASE ship WHEN 'Dec' THEN amount END) AS Dec,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ship IN ('Oct','Nov','Dec') THEN amount END) AS Q4
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Country;
```

Comment: I am using dynamic pivot because the ship by country has calculation logic behind. The table populated is just a sample. Will this work?

Comment: Without a representative example, I have no idea @user3959104 . I can only base an answer off what you've given me.